# Lumen can't validate array of files

Tags: laravel, file, validation, multipartform-data, lumen

I created a webservice using [Lumen 5.7](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.7).

I'm sending an array of files but I can't validate it using the common-known method for validating arrays on Laravel/Lumen:

```php
public function create(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'phone_number' => 'required',
        'latitude' => 'required',
        'longitude' => 'required',
        'status' => 'required', Rule::in(['pre','authorized','archived']),
        'photos' => 'required',
        'photos.*' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,bmp'
    ]);
}
```

It seems to ignore that `photos` rules that I defined there. If i do a `d($request->all())` I got:

[image]

Which means the files reach the server, but they can't be validated.

Here is the html code I'm using to upload the files:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="" action="terrains" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="photos[]" value="" multiple>
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Send">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've also tested it using Postman:

[image]

As you can see, the other validations are being executed correctly except for those of the photos.

I need validations because of several reasons:

- What if the files don't get uploaded?
- What if they files bigger than some requirement?
- What if they are not in the mimetype I want?

Comment: Quite confusing. You uploaded some images...and they showed up. what other validation are you expecting?

Comment: What if they don't get uploaded? What if they are bigger than some requirement? What if they are not in the mimetype I want? There are a lot of what ifs... That's why I need validation.

Also, ain't that weird that is not working even if I'm using the correct implementation?

Comment: These are the ifs you should state in the question. You don't expect us to predict what you have in mind. Edit your question and state all the ifs you want to implement. Then we can proceed from there.

Comment: Done, can you help me?

Comment: I assume that you uploaded files that are not matching the mimes, do they? Just want to make sure :)

Comment: @Tschitsch in the question they are of those mimetypes, so let's say that that is done (for simplicity). 

If I don't send the files, the validation won't show an error (if you want I can add that to the question). 

The thing here is that the validations for the images are being ignored, like they are not there

Answer (score 1):

I will only comment on the new fields I added since you already understand what the other fields do. So, make the following edit.

**Your form:**

```
<form class="" action="terrains" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone Number">
    <input type="text" name="longitude" placeholder="Longitude">
    <input type="text" name="latitude" placeholder="Latitude">
    <input type="text" name="status" placeholder="Status">
    <input type="file" name="photos[]" value="" multiple>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Send">
</form>
```

**Validation:**

```
public function create(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'phone_number' => 'required',   // required translates to the fact that the field must not be empty.
        'latitude' => 'required',
        'longitude' => 'required',
        'status' => 'required', Rule::in(['pre','authorized','archived']),
        'photos' => 'required',
        'photos.*' => 'image|max:5000|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,bmp'    // image = Must be an image, max = The image size must not be bigger than the specified size (5MB)
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Just tried it, still doesn't work.

It works for almost all fields, except for those for the photos, any idea why they would be ignored?

Comment: You are using `Illuminate\Http\Request` right? Any error message? To test if your image validation is working, try to upload a `pdf` file.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `use Illuminate\Http\Request` 

Just tried uploading a pdf, the validation works but only for mimes. If I don't upload any file it won't show an error

Comment: It worked, however I don't understand the change. It literally ended up being the same as when I started. The only change is that I turned off and on my server

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
public function create(Request $request) {
$this->validate($request, [
    'phone_number' => 'required',
    'latitude' => 'required',
    'longitude' => 'required',
    'status' => 'required', Rule::in(['pre','authorized','archived']),
    'photos.*' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,bmp'
]);
```

}